Scroll bar jumps up and down when hiding and showing nested rows
I have issues on scroll bar jumping up and down when hiding and showing nested rows in Tabulator. Nested rows works correctly, but I have to scroll down every time to show expanded rows.
I want it works exactly as here. Can you help me? thanks
I put virtualDom: true and layout: "fitColumns", with no result
